SSRS Subscription Jobs in AG
We use SSRS (SQL Server Reporting Services) for reporting purpose.
The report server is part of AG (Availability Group). We have one primary and three secondary servers. When we create an SSRS subscription, in the background it will create a SQL Agent job on the primary and same job will be replicated to secondary nodes.
My question is, on the secondary nodes, should all these subscription jobs should be disabled?
I have checked on the secondary nodes and found some of the jobs are enabled. so I am not sure if I have to disable

Have you read this Microsoft page already?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/reporting-services-with-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Some tips here https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ensure-that-ssrs-is-working-while-using-availability-groups.  And, in reality, a web search of "ssrs subscription availability group" will give you a number of results with relevant info, tips and workarounds.  I, myself, cannot speak from personal experience, since I have not had to configure SSRS within an AG environment

Does this answers your question https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/283952/ssrs-subscriptions-after-failover/283957#283957

In my environment, I have a two-node SQL 2019 AG with two scaled-out SSRS nodes behind a Windows NLB cluster which works great. When I create a report subscription, I see it created on the Primary node but not the Secondary node. However, when I do a failover to the Secondary node, the SQL Agent job gets automatically created on the Secondary and even with the job enabled on both nodes, it only executes once, and I receive just one email.
